# I have two queueable jobs running in a transaction how to resolve it

Tags: queue, salesforce, future, apex

On Order Product object I have an integration with a 3rd party system, which sends data the 3rd party whenever the Order Product through Queueable class.

Now I am trying to insert a set of records to another object when a particular field in Order product is updated to a certain value using batch apex using the below class.

```
global class CreateScheduleRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    //List<OrderItem> orderProductList = new List<OrderItem>();
    Map<Id, OrderItem> IdOrderItemMapBatch = new Map<Id, OrderItem>();
    List<Schedule__c> scheduleRecordList = new List<Schedule__c>();

    global CreateScheduleRecords(Map<Id, OrderItem> IdOrderItemMap) {
        IdOrderItemMapBatch = IdOrderItemMap;
        System.debug('Akshay is checking the schedule batch ' + IdOrderItemMapBatch);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Order.Id, UnitPrice, Quantity, Pacing__c, OL_Left_To_Deliver__c, Line_Item_Start_Date__c, Line_Item_End_Date__c FROM OrderItem WHERE Id in :IdOrderItemMapBatch.keySet()]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OrderItem> orderProductList) {
        Decimal deliveryQuantity;
        Decimal toBeUpdatedQuantity;
        Integer DeliveryQuantityRemainder;
        String ScheduleDetailsFuture;

        System.debug('Akshay 2 is checking the Queried records ' + orderProductList);
        try {
            for(OrderItem oli : orderProductList) {

                Date a = oli.Line_Item_Start_Date__c;
                Date b = oli.Line_Item_End_Date__c;
                Integer monthDiff = a.monthsBetween(b);
                if (b.day() > a.day()) monthDiff++;
                System.debug('Akshay 3 is checking the difference in the months ' + monthDiff);

                if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Even') {
                    deliveryQuantity = oli.OL_Left_To_Deliver__c / monthDiff;
                    DeliveryQuantityRemainder = math.mod(Integer.valueOf(oli.OL_Left_To_Deliver__c), monthDiff);
                } else if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Front Load') {
                    deliveryQuantity = oli.OL_Left_To_Deliver__c;
                }

                for(Integer i=0; i<monthDiff; i++) {
                    if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Even') {
                        if(DeliveryQuantityRemainder == 0) {
                            toBeUpdatedQuantity = deliveryQuantity;
                        } else {
                            if(i != 1) {
                                toBeUpdatedQuantity = Math.floor(deliveryQuantity);
                            } else {
                                toBeUpdatedQuantity = Math.floor(deliveryQuantity) + DeliveryQuantityRemainder;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Front Load') {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            toBeUpdatedQuantity = deliveryQuantity;
                        } else {
                            toBeUpdatedQuantity = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    Schedule__c sc = new Schedule__c();
                    sc.Delivery_Date__c = System.Date.today().toStartOfMonth();
                    sc.Schedule_Status__c = 'Live';
                    sc.Schedule_Type__c = 'Monthly Forecast';
                    sc.Order_Product__c = oli.Id;
                    sc.Order__c = oli.Order.Id;
                    sc.Unit_Price__c = oli.UnitPrice;
                    sc.Quantity__c = toBeUpdatedQuantity;
                    scheduleRecordList.add(sc);
                }

                System.debug('Akshay 4 is checking the Schedule record list ' + scheduleRecordList);

                if(scheduleRecordList != null && !scheduleRecordList.isempty()) {
                        System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(scheduleRecordList));
                    }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('an error occured while updating the lineitem records ' + e.getMessage() + ' line number ' + e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }


    public class MyQueueable implements Queueable {

        List<Schedule__c> records;
    
        public MyQueueable(List<Schedule__c> records) {
            this.records = records;
        }
    
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            insert records;
        }
    }

}
```

Now when I try to update this field, two separate queueable jobs are running at the same time which in turn is creating the error **"Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2"**
One is the callout that is happening to update the third party and the second is the one that I am running to create a batch of records in another object using the order Item field update.

I tried to use the @future method hoping that it could resolve that, but it didn't work as again it is a queueable method, too.

Can someone please let me know how this can be resolved. Let me know if you need more details on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Instead of enqueuing multiple jobs at once, try chain them. At the end of one Queueable job's execution, enqueue the next job. This ensures only one job is in the queue at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you want to have an enqueued job of ScheduleRecords for every orderItem?
Maybe what's bad is that there are too many enqueued jobs getting created simultaneously.

Consider:

Add to the SELECT statement:

order by Order.Id, Id

Then enqueue a job with a list for each Order.